# Hive partitioning external table based on range

Tags: range, hive, partitioning

I want to partition an external table in hive based on range of numbers. Say numbers with 1 to 100 go to one partition. Is it possible to do this in hive?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you have a table with some records from which you want to load data to an external table which is partitioned by some field say RANGEOFNUMS.

Now, suppose we have a table called testtable with columns name and value. The contents are like

```
India,1 
India,2 
India,3 
India,3 
India,4 
India,10 
India,11 
India,12 
India,13 
India,14
```

Now, suppose we have a external table called testext with some columns along with a partition column say, RANGEOFNUMS.

Now you can do one thing,

```
insert into table testext partition(rangeofnums="your value")
select * from testtable where value>=1 and value<=5;
```

This way all records from the testtable having value 1 to 5 will come into one partition of the external table.

The scenario is my assumption only. Please comment if this is not the scenario you have.

Achyut